# Equality for modulus of 3 complex numbers

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring, absolute-value

Let $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$ $z_1,z_2,z_3 \neq0 $ such that $z_1+z_2+z_3=z^7_1+z^7_2+z^7_3=0$

Prove that $\mid z_1 \mid=\mid z_2 \mid =\mid z_3 \mid $

Any ideas? I was thinking that $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are affixes of the vertices
of an equilateral triangle.

Comment: You could have the $z_k$ being $1$, $0$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z_1=a$, $z_2=b$ and $z_3=c$.

Thus, $c=-a-b$ and
$$0=-a^7-b^7-c^7=(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7=7ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)^2,$$
which gives $$a^2+ab+b^2=0,$$ which gives $$a^3-b^3=0,$$
which gives $$|a|^3=|b|^3,$$ which gives $$|a|=|b|.$$
Now, $$|c|^2=|-a-b|^2=|a^2+2ab+b^2|=|ab|=|a|^2,$$
which gives $$|a|=|b|=|c|.$$
$$(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7=7a^6b+21a^5b^2+35a^4b^3+35a^3b^4+21a^2b^5+7ab^6=$$
$$=7ab(a^5+b^5+3a^4b+3ab^4+5a^3b^2+5a^2b^3)=$$
$$=7ab(a+b)(a^4-a^3b+a^2b^2-ab^3+b^4+3ab(a^2-ab+b^2)+5a^2b^2)=$$
$$=7ab(a+b)(a^4+2a^3b+3a^2b^2+2ab^3+b^4)=$$
$$=7ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)^2.$$

Comment: $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are different from $0$.

Comment: Can you give me an counter-example? I took the problem from a math magazine and i don't think that the problem it's wrong..

Comment: Alright, the problem or Lord Shark’s solution is wrong?

Comment: @Radu Andrei I added something. See now.

Comment: I didn’t learn at school polynomials. Is  any way to factorise $(a+b)^7-a^7-b^7$?

Comment: @Radu Andrei I added something. See now.

Comment: I understand now, thank you sir

Comment: Just one more question: why is $\mid a^2+ab+b^2  \mid=\mid ab \mid$?

Comment: No! $|a^2+ab+b^2|=0,$ But $|a^2+2ab+b^2|=|a^2+ab+b^2+ab|=|0+ab|=|ab|.$

Answer (score 1):

Eliminating $z_3$ gives
$$z_1^7+z_2^7-(z_1+z_2)^7=0.$$
This is
$$z_1^6z_2+3z_1^5z_2^2+5z_1^4z_2^3+5z_1^3z_2^4+3z_1^2z_2^5+z_1z_2^6=0$$
and this factors as
$$z_1z_2(z_1+z_2)(z_1^2+z_1z_2+z_2^2)^2=0.$$
So we could have some $z_k=0$, but otherwise $z_1^2+z_1z_2+z_2^2=0$
etc.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to say that $z_1,z_2,z_3$ are different from $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I should comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Credits to [Lord Shark the Unknown](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/436618/lord-shark-the-unknown) for reducing the problem to $z_1 z_2 (z_1 + z_2)(z_1^2 + z_1 z_2 + z_2^2)^2 = 0$, which is simplified to $z_1^2 + z_1 z_2 + z_2^2 = 0$. 
Solving gives $\frac{z_1}{z_2} = -\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ which is a 3rd root of unity.

You can complete the proof from here.